# Using flat earth projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

This is a flat earth model:

[flatearth](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81hxkBMRufL._AC_SL1500_.jpg)
[image: 2]

Yes, it's funny, no, I'm not a flatearther. My interest is just exploring how the world would look like if the Earth would be flat according to this model.

I don't know too much about QGIS and I would like to start using it. I've succeeded to import geofabrik files.

How can I produce this projection?

Comment: Seems like a North Pole [azimuthal equidistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection) projection. Check if _ESRI:102016_ CRS gives you the desired result.

Comment: By the way, all projections are flat Earth models.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca haha! you're right, about projections and about 102016. If you make it an answer, you've got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printing of the image, not only does it look like a North Pole [azimuthal equidistant  projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection), in fact it seems to be the same printed wikimedia image!

[image: 1]

---

The PROJ projection to transform coordinates to azimuthal equidistant is named `aeqd`: https://proj.org/operations/projections/aeqd.html

The PROJ string for the ellipsoidal (datum WGS84) North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant projection is the following:

`+proj=aeqd +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

It is registered in ESRI Authority with the ID 102016, and its Well Known Text (WKT) is the following:

```
PROJCRS["North_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant",
    BASEGEODCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["North_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant",
        METHOD["Modified Azimuthal Equidistant",
            ID["EPSG",9832]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",90,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AREA["World - north of 0°N"],
    BBOX[0,-180,90,180],
    ID["ESRI",102016]]
```

---

Due to some difference in versions, I never quite understood whether from PROJ or GDAL, in QGIS 3.4.13 the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) is found as *EPSG:102016*, but in QGIS 3.10.0 it is found as *ESRI:102016*.

Anyway, you can search for it by number and you will find it:

[image]